# OpenCV Frame Grabber not work on MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos, opencv, kotlin, javacv

**Short version:**

when I'm type this command in macOS Catalina terminal:

```
java -jar test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

gets the result:

```
Start App
zsh: abort         java -jar test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**More details:**

My main feature in app is based on webcam capture and I have a requirement for the application to work on Windows 10, Linux and MacOS. That's why I decided to choose JavaCV to handle webcam capturning. Everything works fine on windows and linux. However, it doesn't work properly on MacOS. For testing the application on a Mac, I'm using virtual box 6.1 and macOS Catalina 10.15.5. In project I'm also using gradle and kotlin.

I also checked if I have access to the camera from virtual machine and the camera works correctly in system applications. I suspect that the application is not working due to camera permissions.

I will also add that the macOS Catalina is up to date

**Basic code**

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.3'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "App"
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    exclude('META-INF/*.SF')
    exclude('META-INF/*.DSA')
    exclude('META-INF/*.RSA')
    exclude('module-info.class')
}
mainClassName = 'App'
```

App.kt

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber

class App {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Start App")
            val grabber: OpenCVFrameGrabber = OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
            grabber.start()
        }
    }
}
```

In order to create executable jar file, I'm type this in mac terminal:

```
sudo 
./gradlew clean build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problem with macOS was that the app should ask for camera access before launching it. Jar files are not treated as applications by macOS.
[More info here](https://www.howtogeek.com/361707/how-macos-mojaves-privacy-protection-works/). For example, when you running the application by IDE, system will ask you for access to the camera.